# Next and Previous ID with WHERE slow

Tags: mysql, performance, pagination

i am trying to solve a performance issue.
I have a table called "pages" which contains thousands of pages.
There is a field called "status" which can be 0,1,2 and i want to select only 1 and 2 but not 0. As soon as i add the additional AND != 0 or IN (1,2) or >= 1 this query takes 0,5 seconds, without it its quiet fast.

Here are my queries:

```
SELECT name, pages.id, urlString, metaTitle, metaDescription, id, 
anchorText
                    FROM pages 
                    INNER JOIN metaDe 
                    ON pages.id=metaDe.pageId 
                    WHERE id = (SELECT min(id) FROM pages WHERE 
linkToPageFunction = ? AND id > ? AND status != 0 )
                    LIMIT 1

                    SELECT name, pages.id, urlString, metaTitle, 
metaDescription, id, anchorText
                    FROM pages 
                    INNER JOIN metaDe 
                    ON pages.id=metaDe.pageId 
                    WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM pages WHERE 
linkToPageFunction = ? AND id < ? AND status != 0 )
                    LIMIT 1
```

without "AND status != 0" it is fast.
I want it to be fast plus if possible i want to use one query which returns two results (previous and next) instead of using two queries.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

EDIT EXPLAIN:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'select_type' => 'PRIMARY',
    'table' => 'metaDe',
    'type' => 'const',
    'possible_keys' => 'PRIMARY,pageId_2,pageId,pageId_3,idxMetaDePageId',
    'key' => 'PRIMARY',
    'key_len' => '4',
    'ref' => 'const',
    'rows' => 1,
    'Extra' => 'Using where',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'select_type' => 'PRIMARY',
    'table' => 'pages',
    'type' => 'const',
    'possible_keys' => 'PRIMARY,id,id_2,id_3',
    'key' => 'PRIMARY',
    'key_len' => '4',
    'ref' => 'const',
    'rows' => 1,
    'Extra' => 'Using where; Using index',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'select_type' => 'SUBQUERY',
    'table' => 'pages',
    'type' => 'ref',
    'possible_keys' => 'PRIMARY,linkToPageFunction,id,status,id_2,id_3,idxPagesForStatusQuery,idxPagesStatus',
    'key' => 'idxPagesForStatusQuery',
    'key_len' => '93',
    'ref' => 'const',
    'rows' => 298725,
    'Extra' => 'Using where; Using index',
  ),
)array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'select_type' => 'PRIMARY',
    'table' => 'pages',
    'type' => 'const',
    'possible_keys' => 'PRIMARY,id,id_2,id_3',
    'key' => 'PRIMARY',
    'key_len' => '4',
    'ref' => 'const',
    'rows' => 1,
    'Extra' => 'Using index',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'select_type' => 'PRIMARY',
    'table' => 'metaDe',
    'type' => 'const',
    'possible_keys' => 'PRIMARY,pageId_2,pageId,pageId_3,idxMetaDePageId',
    'key' => 'PRIMARY',
    'key_len' => '4',
    'ref' => 'const',
    'rows' => 1,
    'Extra' => '',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'select_type' => 'SUBQUERY',
    'table' => 'pages',
    'type' => 'range',
    'possible_keys' => 'PRIMARY,linkToPageFunction,id,status,id_2,id_3,idxPagesForStatusQuery,idxPagesStatus',
    'key' => 'idxPagesForStatusQuery',
    'key_len' => '97',
    'ref' => NULL,
    'rows' => 5,
    'Extra' => 'Using where; Using index',
  ),
)
```

### Since i cannot answer this thread for whatever reason, i am giving my answer and solutions here.

Thanks everybody. Sometimes you need to thing and talk about to fix it. I guess i just found the (simple) solution.

Thats what i am doing now. I have no idea why i havent got this way before.

**Next**:

```
            SELECT name, pages.id, urlString, metaTitle, metaDescription, id, anchorText
            FROM pages 
            INNER JOIN metaDe 
            ON pages.id=metaDe.pageId 
            WHERE id > ? AND status IN (1, 2) AND linkToPageFunction = ?
            ORDER BY id ASC  LIMIT 1
```

**Previous**:

```
            SELECT name, pages.id, urlString, metaTitle, metaDescription, id, anchorText
            FROM pages 
            INNER JOIN metaDe 
            ON pages.id=metaDe.pageId 
            WHERE id < ? AND status IN (1, 2) AND linkToPageFunction = ?
            ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Kindly post output of `EXPLAIN SELECT`

Comment: Added Explain to the above.

Comment: That's not a readable explain output.. please, put some effort in your question. Are you able to read this without issues? You can take a look at similar questions to see how they provide EXPLAIN output.

Comment: I edited it and added the below comments index (create index idxPagesForStatusQuery on pages (linkToPageFunction, id, status);
) its still not really fast (0,4 sec) and i edited the explain above this time with var_export(), which should be more pretty.

Comment: I believe what @Mjh meant was to post a screenshot from your explain select command result, taken from a client app, such as mysql workbench, hence, showing it as a table, or image.

Comment: This is currently not possible, sorry. I cannot currently access this db from outside by any app. This output isnt the nicest, but should still contain the needed information plus i am trying to give as much input as possible.

Comment: Isnt it possible to combine this into one Query?
I want to create get the next and previous (existing) page with a status of 1 or 2 while joining their metaData in the current language (metaDe).

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to write the sql the other way around like: select min(p.id), b.name, ... from pages p  left join pages b on b.id=p.id left join metaDe m on m.pageId=p.id where p.id>? and status in (1,2) and linkFunction=? ....

Comment: No, i havent. Cannot follow you (yet). I would love to have one query which returns both, next and previous while staying fast. I am of course caching this, but initial load time is important, so i cannot use this live currently.

Comment: maybe creating a workable sample on sqlfiddle.com with your schema (related 3 tables, existing indexes, keys and foreign keys) and a few rows of sample data could help ? As it is, those indexes should have helped, and rewriting the query as joins instead of subselects should have helped too (as in my last comment).

Comment: check here please: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/73MByi6szfigej1DECoCD5/0#&togetherjs=lDlaxKDEj8 for a workable and single query sample, if schema is accurate etc. I had to guess a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to have an index on your `pages` table that includes the `status` field. Add such an index and your query speed should improve a lot.

```
create index idxPagesStatus on pages (status);
```

or even

```
create index idxPagesForStatusQuery on pages (linkToPageFunction, id, status);
```

to include all fields in the query. Also, on your metaDe tabke pageId could use an index as well.

```
create index idxMetaDePageId on metaDe (pageId);
```

also, if you know the pages.id key is sequential for sure(ie, goes like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...), and none is deleted, you could simply do:

```
SELECT
  name,
  pages.id,
  urlString,
  metaTitle,
  metaDescription,
  id, 
  anchorText
FROM
  pages 
left JOIN
  metaDe ON pages.id=metaDe.pageId 
WHERE 
  abs(2-id)=1;
```

Comment: Edited, see comment above

Comment: This is the fastest solution, but sadly i cant guarantee that all ids exist, so  i can only select ids which exist and which have status 1 or 2, but not 0.
My solution above is still 0,3s slow, the query cache was confusing me.
Any ideas?

Comment: If there is no solid solution i might save those urls instead of generating them in runtime which would be a lot of extra work. Hmmm.

Comment: Have you any idea left?